# Is Pathauto designed to modify URL requests?

Tags: path-aliases

I have configured Pathauto to redirect /node/23 to /resource/resourcename. Should it render menus as /resource/resourcename, or still /node/23? If a user requests /node/23, is Pathauto supposed to change the request to /resource/resourcename?

Currently, it does allow for /resource/resourcename to be used, but it does not actively change /node/23 if it is entered.

Comment: Do you also have GlobalRedirect installed/enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Pathauto only creates path aliases for nodes, users, etc. based on patterns, i.e. `/node/23` will also work with `/resource/resourcename`. However, no redirect is made. If you wish to redirect the node path to the path alias you could use the [Global redirect module](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect).

Once an alias is created all menus etc. will use the alias instead of the real path, in fact, all links created with the `l()` (`url()`) function.